# How to validate packets from socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, security, socket.io

Hi I'm writing a game with `node.js`, `socket.io`, and `canvas` and was wondering how to validate packets properly. I'm under the impression that users can use a packet injection program to send packets that the server isn't expecting. For example,

- Send a packet with one of the parameters outside of normal bounds (x or y beyond game space)
- Send extremely large packets to overwhelm the server
- Send a packet with additional parameters the server is not expecting
- Send a packet with data that, when read, may execute commands on the server (escape characters?)
- Send the same packet over and over to overwhelm the server (DoS)

What are the typical measures taken to prevent such things? Are some of the bullets not an actually issue? Am I missing anything? Are there any libraries to assist in any of this?

Comment: The technique you're describing is called [*Fuzz Testing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing). There are automated tools for doing this kind of testing; there's none I can recommend specifically, so I'll leave that up to your own research. In general, though you should be validating all input, no matter the source, to make sure it fits what is expected, and things like (D)DoS are a specific class of concern not easily managed by the server, much less the server scripting engine. The idea is if someone submits a 2mb string of characters instead of 1/0 value, that triggers an error.

Comment: yes, you should always validate user input, even from sockets. your 4th case won't happen.

Comment: @dandavis: It very much depends on what the server is doing. For example, if it calling OS command directly then see this article [OS Command Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Command_Injection_(OTG-INPVAL-013)) for some examples of what can go wrong. Also, if there is any native code running this might be susceptible to buffer overflows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll take these one at a time:

> Send a packet with one of the parameters outside of normal bounds (x
>   or y beyond game space)

This is totally up to your server code test all incoming values to make sure they are within appropriate bounds.

> Send extremely large packets to overwhelm the server

There is a separate discussion about how to protect socket.io from this kind of DOS attack.  I will go look for a link and edit when I find it.

> Send a packet with additional parameters the server is not expecting

Again, this is entirely up to your server to validate all incoming data.  Additional parameters are probably just ignored by your code.   Socket.io uses the JSON format for sending data which is "safe".  Extra parameters would just be hanging out and as long as your code doesn't access them, they do no harm.  Just a little extra junk sitting around in the message.

> Send a packet with data that, when read, may execute commands on the
>   server (escape characters?)

This would not normally be possible unless your server does something dangerous in processing the data.  As I said before, all data is sent as JSON which is parsed in a safe manner which does not have any known vulnerabilities for escape characters or other such things.  You will have to make sure you are fully validating any data you process so that you don't risk opening your own server to things like SQL injection, etc...  This all has to do with what you do with incoming data (particularly strings).   Things like calling `eval()` on strings sent to you are very dangerous, but that is not normally something one would do.

> Send the same packet over and over to overwhelm the server (DoS)

The usual protection for this is rate limiting where you limit the number of packets that a single client can send within a given time.  If they exceed some threshold, you disconnect them.  If they continue, you ban their user account.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! :D

Comment: Great answer. Did you find a good link for the `Send extremely large packets to overwhelm the server`? Haven't found one myself, sadly.

Comment: @Tholle - I did not find protection from large packets.  There's discussion of people wanting it, but I didn't find discussion of any sort of implementation.

Comment: I see. Will probably look into implementing it myself. Thank you for your time.